Solutions to $y'=y$
This is a pretty famous ODE.
Solution
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y\implies \frac{dy}{y}=dx$$
Integrate both sides and we get
$$\ln y=x+C \implies y=C_1e^x$$
My question
Why is $y=0$ not a valid solution?
$C_1=e^C$, so it can't be $0$, because $\exp(x)>0\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$
Edit
Rephrasing my question, I want to know what approach should I have taken to get both solutions

We, $C_1=-1$ is also a solution. Anyway, when you divided by $y,$ you implicitly excluded $y=0$ from your solution.

@ThomasAndrews Oh, that's why then. But then is this loss of data?  Also we can take imaginary values for arbitrary constant? For $C_1=-1$, we need $C=iπ$ right?

Sorry, edited it to be $C_1=-1.$ Then $C_1=e^C$ is only possible if $C$ is a complex.

The test of whether something is a solution is whether, when you plug it into the equation, both sides are equal, not whether any particular method finds it.

@ZoeAllen it seems quite right as they do get equal

@Moo sadly I'm in highschool so I didn't know about Direction field plots :")  It will be really helpful if you can provide a website where I can learn and understand it. Thanks in advance :)

You shouldn't ask "why $y=0$ is not a valid solution?" because it obviously is a solution. You should ask "Why with this method I didn't find the obvious solution $y=0$?"

If $y=0$ for every $x$, then also $y'=0$ for every $x$. So $y=0$ is a valid solution for your question.

@jjagmath edited my question. Thanks for the recommendation

(1) To get a Solution , the method here assumes that $y$ is not Zero when dividing by $y$ , hence it gets excluded. (2) You can consider the Case $y=0$ & check whether that is a Solution , which it indeed is. (3) You should use $|y|$ when integrating $1/y$ (4) Put that all together to get all the Solutions Cases.

I have no idea what you mean by "loss of data," since there is no data that I can see in this question. If we solve $x^2=x$ by dividing both sides by $x,$ you get $x=1,$ but that is not the only possible answer - we forgot to check what happens when $x=0.$ I'm not sure I'd call that "loss of data."

Well $C$ can be any complex number, so it turns out that $C_1$ can be any complex number too. So you indeed have $y=Ce^x$ and if only real functions are to be considered, then $C\in \mathbb R$.

This approach gives you all the solutions:
First, note that $e^x$ is a solution. Suppose that $f$ is any other solution and consider $g(x)=f(x)e^{-x}$. Then $g'(x)=f'(x)e^{-x}-f(x)e^{-x} = 0$, so $g(x) = C$ with $C \in \Bbb R$.
This means that all the solutions are $f(x)= g(x)e^x=C e^x$ with $C\in \Bbb R$. This includes $C=0$ (which is the solution you were asking about) and $C<0$ which apparently you didn't notice that were missing.

Thanks, I can see it now
